# Calculating distance between 2 latitudes and longitudes using data frames in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, data-science

```
from math import sin, cos, sqrt, atan2, radians

R = 6373.0

datacopy['dlon'] = datacopy['dropoff_longitude'].apply(lambda a: radians(a)) - datacopy['pickup_longitude'].apply(lambda b: radians(b))
datacopy['dlat'] = datacopy['dropoff_latitude'].apply(lambda c: radians(c)) - datacopy['pickup_latitude'].apply(lambda d: radians(d))

datacopy['C'] = datacopy['dlat'].apply(lambda x: sin(x/2)**2) + datacopy['pickup_latitude'].apply(lambda y: cos(y))* datacopy['dropoff_latitude'].apply(lambda w: cos(w)) * datacopy['dlon'].apply(lambda v: sin(v/2)**2)

datacopy['A'] = datacopy['C'].apply(lambda t: 2 * atan2(sqrt(t), sqrt(1-t)))
```

After running the last code I'm getting this error

```
   ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-802b028ec41e> in <module>
----> 1 datacopy['c'] = datacopy['Z'].apply(lambda t: 2 * atan2(sqrt(t), sqrt(1-t)))

~\anaconda3\envs\cv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   4198             else:
   4199                 values = self.astype(object)._values
-> 4200                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   4201 
   4202         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-20-802b028ec41e> in <lambda>(t)
----> 1 datacopy['c'] = datacopy['Z'].apply(lambda t: 2 * atan2(sqrt(t), sqrt(1-t)))

ValueError: math domain error
```

I checked out how to calculate distance between 2 longitudes and latitudes from stack overflow, I am applying it in data frames but getting this error. Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow")! It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing the data that produces your problem. Please read about how to ask a good question and try to post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") so we can better help you.

Comment: As indicated above, we can only guess whats wrong based on the error. Since the error states a `math domain error, it is likely that `sqrt(t)`  is trying to take the root of a negative number. For debug purposes, it would help if you write the loop explicitly, without the `apply` method. and print the value that produces the exact error.